# Plotting Grid in R

Tags: r, plot, grid

Plz, I'm a beginner in R programming. I have an Excel with columns:

```
GridNUM, Long, Lat and Values
```

So I want to plot this data grid in my shapefile like the example
[image]

Comment: Please visit [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Please provide your data in `dput()` format.

Comment: this should help http://www.milanor.net/blog/maps-in-r-plotting-data-points-on-a-map/